# Using unlocking code to unlock android application

Tags: android

please i want to develop an application in android that can accept unlocking code before one can use it.I don't want to use google play or any other app market, i want to transfer the app from my PC to any android device before or after installation the application will ask for unlocking code else the app will not run. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your MainActivity layout blank.  Then in the onCreate, add an alert like so:

```
final ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert, null);
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Enter Code")
    .setMessage("Enter Code to continue")
    .setView(layout)
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            EditText et = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.et_value);
            if (et.getText().equals("12345")) startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
            else MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    })
    .show();
```

The layout, "layout_alert" would only contain an EditText field:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

If you don't care if the user sees the main activity, you can replace

```
if (et.getText().equals("12345")) startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
else MainActivity.this.finish();
```

with

```
if(!et.getText().equals("12345")) MainActivity.this.finish();
```

Edit:

I had some spare time today, so I wrote up a quick example app:

https://github.com/michami/LockedUp

Comment: I rename it to my current layout and the error disappear

Comment: "layout_alert" is a new layout you add as a resource.  Just copy the code I posted.

Comment: I did as you said but it takes me to home screen instead of new activity

Comment: Replace `SecondActivity.class` with the name of the activity you want it to go to.

Comment: I changed my answer with an example of using one activity.

Comment: It accept anything not particularly the code number(12345) inside the code. If i type 123456 if accept

Comment: And please i want it to be one-time login

Comment: I added an example app to my answer.